# Variable scope within function

Tags: javascript, sapui5

Read lots of posts lately, trying to demystify variable scopes in Javascript/SAPUI5. The way that I have understood things we have mainly 2 kinds of them - local variables, declared inside functions and visible only within and global variables declared outside functions and therefore "globally" accessible. Tried that with a really small example and, after what debugging revealed, I feel quite puzzled here. Tiny sample below:

```
onTestButtonPress: function() {
        var url = "/DEV/sap/opu/odata/SAP/ZCONTRACTS_SRV/Agreement_ExportSet";
        var oTest1 = [];
        var promise = $.Deferred();

        $.ajax({                
            url: url,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(xhrData) {
                var oTest2 = xhrData;
                promise.resolve();
            }
        });

        var readyToGo = function() {
            jQuery.sap.log.error("check");
        };

        jQuery.when(promise).done().then( jQuery.proxy(readyToGo, this) );              
    }
```

On $.ajax... and jQuery.when... statements, oTest1 var has a value of [] while within the functions contained in the main function (ajax success function & readyToGo), same variable is producing a reference error.

According to the "theory" and unless I miss something, since oTest1 was declared at the beginning of the main function, it should be visible within the two nested functions as well. What do I miss here or, to put it in a different way, where (or how maybe?) should I declare my variable in the function in order to be visible?

Thanks in advance,

Greg

UPDATE: After a (fair) suggestion, modified the code and attached code for the variable in doubt. New code is this:

```
    onTestButtonPress: function() {
        var url = "/DEV/sap/opu/odata/SAP/ZCONTRACTS_SRV/Agreement_ExportSet";
        var oTest1 = [];
        var promise = $.Deferred();

        $.ajax({                
            url: url,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(xhrData) {
                oTest1 = xhrData;
                promise.resolve();
            }
        });

        var readyToGo = function() {
            jQuery.sap.log.error(oTest1);
        };

        jQuery.when(promise).done().then( jQuery.proxy(readyToGo, this) );              
    }
```

This code is running just fine and variable is OK. Still running the old code, debugger produces this:

[image]

This is the reason that I didn't use the var in the sample, is this normal?

Comment: You don't use `oTest1` in any of the nested functions. You need to provide a [mcve] which actually shows your problem.

Comment: Quentin: the reason that I didn't do it is simply to provide a running example, I can put code for this variable in there but it will crash

Comment: The crash is what you are asking about. Being able to see it is really important!

Comment: Quentin: you were absolutely right. Relatively new at this, never crossed my mind that debugger could have such a behavior. This has turned to be something different that variable scope...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get an error in the code in the screenshot because `oTest1` is not in scope.

Scope is determined when the function is created, and since the `oTest1` variable is not used in the function then it isn't in scope.

You attempt to add it to the scope after the function has been created by reading the variable with the debugger. It is too late.

Add `console.log(oTest1)` before `debugger` and it will be in scope.